# Can anyone explain why my database would be one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many?

Tags: many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many, one-to-one

I am struggling to figure out the relationship between ingredient and shampoo table. I have a join table between these tables called Shampoo_Ingredients. How do I figure out if these tables would be one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, or many-to-many? Thanks for any help you can provide. This has been a really frustrating concept to me.

[Image of DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ0Ic.png)

Comment: I am thinking that the Shampoo table is ManyToMany because every shampoo has many times of ingredients.

Comment: but then I start wondering what would the relationship be when talking about Ingredients table.

Comment: Shampoo_Ingredients should be many to many, shampoo and Ingredients will one to many , company and shampoo will be one to one

Comment: It's simple: you just need to ask yourself these questions: Does a given shampoo have several ingredients, and is a given ingredient used in several shampoo? If yes, it's a ManyToMany. Does a shampoo have several ingredients, but each ingredient is used in only one champoo. If yes, it's a OneToMany. Does a shampoo have a single ingredient, and is an ingredient used by a single shampoo? If yes, it's a OneToOne.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shampoo has many ingredients. An ingredient can be in many different shampoos.

So, you have a many-to-many using a join table Shampoo_ingredients.